# Elasticsearch nested aggregation ratios using nested and root level data

Tags: elasticsearch

I have what feels like a simple aggregation. I have a document that's timing code like so:

```
{
  "task_start": "2020-06-03T21:19:07.908821Z",
  "task_end": "2020-06-03T21:27:00.323790Z",
  "sub_tasks": [
    {
      "key": "sub-task1-time-milliseconds",
      "value": 3310
    },
    {
      "key": "sub-task2-time-milliseconds",
      "value": 2410
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

where sub_tasks is nested. What I'd like to get is the median ratio of time in each sub task to the entire task time. The entire task time would be just `end_time - start_time`. I know how to aggregate the median sub task time and total task time individually. But I'd like to aggregate the ratio per document.

The issue is on a nested aggregation I can only access data with the nested data, and within a reverse nested aggregation I can only access data at the root level, but never both together. I understand there's a way to [copy_to](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html) so I have the task times in the nested path, but I don't have the ability to modify the indexing structure, and wouldn't want the extra storage either.

Here's what I've tried. For a nested aggregation:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "task_metrics": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "sub_tasks"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sub_task_metrics": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "sub_tasks.key": "sub-task1-time-milliseconds"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "median_time": {
              "percentiles": {
                "script": {
                  "lang": "painless",
                  "source": """
                            double task_time = (doc['task_end'].value.millis - doc['task_start'].value.millis);
                            return doc['sub_tasks.value'].value / task_time; 
                            """
                },
                "percents": 50
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But in that aggregation `doc['task_start']` and `doc['task_end']` just return zero because I don't have access to them. To get access, I also tried a `reverse_nested` that adds another sub aggregation. This gets me access to `doc['task_start']` and `doc['task_end']`, but then `doc['sub_tasks.value'].value` just returns `0`.

It just *feels* like this should be possible, but when I read over pipeline aggregations and other script aggregations, I don't believe any of those do what I want. Greatly appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one's tricky -- already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51710652/8160318).

I think you'll have to resort a bit of `scripted_metric`s and some method mocking because the exposed painless API is [somewhat limited](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/painless-api-reference-shared.html):

```json
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "task_metrics_median": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": "state.ratios = new ArrayList();",

        "map_script": """
          // access the source incl. the nested subtasks
          def d = params._source;

          for (def subtask : d.sub_tasks) {
            // mimicking a `term` query
            if (subtask.key != 'sub-task1-time-milliseconds') break;
           
            // incoming as strings so parse
            def millis_end = ZonedDateTime.parse(d.task_end).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
            def millis_start = ZonedDateTime.parse(d.task_start).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
            
            double task_time = (millis_end - millis_start);

            // prevent zero division
            if (task_time <= 0) break;

            state['ratios'].add(subtask.value / task_time);  
          }
        """,

        "combine_script": """
            def ratios = state.ratios;
            Collections.sort(ratios);
            
            // trivial median calc
            double median;
            if (ratios.length % 2 == 0) {
                median = ((double)ratios[ratios.length/2] + (double)ratios[ratios.length/2 - 1])/2;
            } else {
                median = (double) ratios[ratios.length/2];
            }

            return median
        """,

        "reduce_script": "return states"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Joe! That does indeed work! As I had read before, the use of `params` is rather slow however, so I have to downsample heavily with `sampler` for it to work, but it works as a rough estimate. Thanks again!

Comment: Cool! Glad I could help.