# Iterate and query for range of dates in ELK (Elastic Kibana)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk

We're using (trying to use) ELK in an eCommerce context.  Sales, Averages, Sales by Currency, by Country etc.  All works well.  The next chart we need to build is a forecast over the next 30 days.  So in pseudo C# it would look like this:

```
for ( var reportDate = DateTime.UTCNow; reportDate < DateTime.UTCNow.AddDays(31) ; reportDate.AddDays(1) {
        // query on reportDate and add some stuff up
}
```

Are we asking a bit much of ELK?  I can do this for a given day by using a scripted field.  Just wondering if there's a way to make a bar chart with the x axis a rolling series of dates, and the y axis a sum for those dates.  I'd started to write this as a C# report but am curious to know whether ELK would cover this kind of thing natively.

I could probably do this with a scripted field for each of the 30 days.  So 30 scripted fields.  One where we query on today, then add 1 day, then two days etc?  Feels a bit cumbersome, though.
Any ideas welcome
Thanks.

Comment: Why is the `kibana` tag included? Are you mentioning it just because it's part of the ELK stack or do you want to display the resulting rolling date series within Kibana?

Comment: Kibana is tagged because I want to make a bar chart (in Kibana) with my 30 days as the x axis values and the calc for each day as the y axis value.  Apologies if this wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

Scripted fields cannot be used in a (date histogram) aggregation because they're executed in the search context which is different from the aggregations' context.

Your use case sounds custom enough to have to resort to a [`scripted_metric`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html).

[Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62249232/8160318) using some date parsing & basic stats math.