# Calculating median response times of messages

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

**Sample Documents:**

```
{
   "id":123,
   "message_type":"RECEIVE",
   "conversation_id":"1"
   "date":"2020-01-01T12:00:00"
},
{
   "id":456,
   "message_type":"SEND",
   "conversation_id":"1"
   "date":"2020-01-01T13:00:00"
},
{
   "id":789,
   "message_type":"SEND",
   "conversation_id":"1"
   "date":"2020-01-01T14:00:00"
}
```

**Context:**

1. The responses to a messages are not nested under the message. Neither do they share the parent/child relationship.
2. Every sent message is to be considered as a reply of last received message. (I understand it may look odd but it is the case)

**Ask:** To calculate median response times of messages month over month.

**Problem:** Median calculation may not be a problem but i am not sure how to calculate response times considering flat hierarchy of documents.

**My Attempt:**

1. For every new sent message, tag the response time with last received message in the conversation.
2. Process old conversations/messages for #1.

Any better way of doing this? Can pipeline aggregation be used for that?

Answer (score 1):

There may be a way to achieve this using pipeline aggs that I'm not aware of but since the documents' contexts aren't 'aware' of each other, you may need to use scripted metrics for this.

The pseudocode looks like this:

1. **init:** initialze an empty hash map of month - vs - hash maps of messages grouped by the id
2. **map:** iterate over all queried docs and assign them to the correct map leaves
3. **combine:** calculate the medians and other metrics
4. **reduce:** return the metrics in the format of your choice

Here's a [concrete, similar example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62249232/8160318). Disregard the `nested` aspect -- the principle still stands.

Comment: It is indeed helpful. Let me try it out. Do you have any idea about approx how long would it take for a prod-grade machine, considering 1 million document ?

Comment: I will try this out. Got occupied with something.